# How to write a SpecFlow step to check value that is known only at the test execution time?

Tags: automated-tests, specflow

I need to check the values in the table on the Web page. In most cases these are pre-known values. But sometimes the value is, for example, the current date. Is it possible to write something like "= today ()" in the "Then" step, and not create a new step only for this case?
So can I do something like this by means of SpecFlow:

`Then I verify values in MyTable
| ColumnA     | ColumnB |ColumnC   |
| Electricity | 100     | =today() |
| Electricity | 200     | =today() |`

Answer (score 0):

If the value has to come from a table then you can just check for your known values and create the dates from them. Something along these untested lines:

```
[Then("I verify values in MyTable")]
public void ThenIVerifyValuesInMyTable(Table table)
{
    foreach(var row in table.Rows)
    {
        DateTime comparisonDate;
        if (row[2].Value =='Today')
        {
             comparisonDate=DateTime.Today;
        }
        else
        { 
            comparisonDate = DateTime.Parse(row[2]);
        }
        comparisonDate.Should().Be(myTable.ExpectedDate);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope here is an answer
[Default Values Specflow Step Definitions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4922547/default-values-specflow-step-definitions)
SpecFlow supports creating "step argument transformations". With them, you can create methods that can parse datetime from different patterns:

```
[StepArgumentTransformation("todays date")]
  public DateTime TransformToday()
  {
    return DateTime.Today;
  }
```

After that, you just need to use a DateTime param in your steps and the rest is done by SpecFlow...

```
[Given(@"myfield equals (.*)")`enter code here`]
   public void MyfieldEqualsTodaysDate(DateTime date)
   {
      //do stuff
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this will work with a table argument, you would have to put the value in a step definition or use examples

Comment: Well I was not able to check with table arguments. But I checked follwing quick example[Then(@"I verify values in table with date")]
        public void ThenIVerifyValuesInTableWithDate(Table table)
        {
            var rr = table.CreateInstance<MyTable>();
            Debug.Print(rr.ColumnC.ToString());
        }


       
    }

    public class MyTable
    {
        
        public string ColumnnA { get; set; }
        public string ColumnnB { get; set; }

        public DateTime ColumnC
        {
            get { return DateTime.UtcNow; }
            set{};
        }
    }

Comment: this assumes that your column always contains the same data, in which case there is no point in having it in the table

Comment: plus better to edit your  answer and include the code than put code in the comments...